# Can't load relationship using "get" Ember 3.2

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to load a relationship I know hasn't been loaded before, but it seems that it's never calling my API for it.

My setup is:

```
// routes/application.js
export default Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.get('store').findRecord('post', 1, {include: 'user'});
    }
});

// routes/comments.js
export default Route.extend({
    model() {
        let post = this.modelFor('application');
        return post.get('user').get('actionHistory');
    }
});
```

The users `actionHistory` hasn't loaded before, so I would expect a server request to fetch it, but that's never made. `user` is available.

```
// models/user.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    actionHistory: DS.hasMany('action-history'),
    ...
});

// models/action-history.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
    ...
});
```

I've tried many ways to make sure it's loaded, `post.load('user.actionHistory')`, `post.get('user').reload({ include: 'action-history'})`, but nothing works.

Is there something wrong with my setup, or the way that I'm trying to fetch the relationship?

Comment: As I remember, in recent versions ember-data does not load relationships by itself. I think something like `return this.store.findRecord('action-history', post.get('user').get('actionHistory.id');` might work in your case

Comment: @GennadyDogaev Yeah, I've resorted to just doing a findAll() for action history and letting that be the model for my route, but I'm a bit sad now that I can load a relationship from one route and have it propagated to the ember store if I ever need it again without fetching from the server :(

Comment: Can you show how you've loaded the user? Have you provided a related link?

Comment: Is `post.get('user')` there actually returning a valid instance of the User model?

Comment: Could you please include payload returned by fetching user? Are you using JSON API? If so: are you using [relationship links](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-relationships)? I assume it's not a [compound document](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents) cause otherwise you would not expect any request, wouldn't you?

Comment: I think post.get('user') returns a promise proxy, so you need to call .then on it before you can call .get('actionHistory')

Answer (score 1):

As Gaurav mentioned in a comment ember-datas `findRecord` function will return a promise that needs to resolve first. After it has resolved you should be able to get the user then. For example, the following will return a promise as your model that will resolve to a users action history.

```
// routes/comments.js
export default Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.modelFor('application').then(p => p.get('user.actionHistory'));
    }
});
```

> Note that your comments controller/template will not receive a promise from your model hook as ember will wait for it to resolve first.